# How can I create a formula that counts the number of duplicates, returns the value in a cell of my choosing, and then deletes the duplicates?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, duplicate, blank

I've got a list that, after I sort it, looks like this:

[rough list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJy55.png)

I need a formula that will return the number of times each entry is listed and delete all the duplicates.  Typically, I simply count the number with my eyes or highlight those that are identical and record the "count" calculated at the bottom of the spreadsheet.  Then I go back through and delete all duplicates, which is a bit of a tedious process and I can't help but think that there is an easier way to do this.

I have tried using the filter feature to return entries that don't have a number in the adjacent column, but when I go to remove the duplicates, entries are shifted up so that the numbers I have already typed in by hand get mismatched.  Truth be told, I have a feeling that there's a way to have Excel count and record the number of times each entry appears (without even having to sort through it first), but I'm weak on logical formulas and the searches I've done of the world wide web have resulted in related queries, but don't really help me figure out how to do this.

Currently I use a Microsoft 365 version of Excel.

Ultimately, I want the list to look like this:

[finished list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnGRH.jpg)

but with less effort.

For those who want even more detail, read on for the bigger picture.  As someone interested in eating for health, I track my consumption down to the micronutrient to ensure I'm getting adequate amounts and not exceeding any recommended limits.  Once a week, I review this data and identify nutrients I'm not getting enough of.  I have a master spreadsheet of sorts that lists the foods that are richest in various nutrients.  It looks like this:

[list of nutrients and the foods richest in them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV7nD.jpg)

As you can see, certain foods appear on more than one list, and because I can only eat so much food in a day, I want to concentrate on those that give me more bang for the buck because they appear on more than one list.  Typically, I just copy and paste the columns for which deficiencies were identified into a single column and then sort it alphabetically to get a count.  I add this detail because I have a feeling that a true SuperUser of Excel wouldn't even have to bother with the clunky copy and paste that I do and could just pull the number from this master spreadsheet of foods by nutrients.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me use Excel a bit more efficiently.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but I don't really know how to make it any more detailed than I already have.  If you still really think this, could you be more specific on how I could be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following data and using `MS365` then you can do the following methods:

| Fiber | Calcium | Iron | Magnesium | Zinc | Copper | Manganese | Iodine | Selenium | Fluoride |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| navy beans | milk | fortified cereals | pumpkin seeds | beef | crab | wheat germ | baked potato | Brazil nuts | black tea |
| lentils | yogurt | wheat bran flakes | almonds | pumpkin seeds | lobster | sweet potatoes | milk | sunflower seeds | shrimp |
| pinto beans | parmesan | grits | spinach | sunflower seeds | shiitakes | collard greens | shrimp | tuna | raisins |
| chickpeas | Swiss | granola | black beans | lentils | white buttons | peas | turkey | salmon | raspberries |
| lima beans | cottage cheese | shredded wheat | salmon | turkey | portabellas | pine nuts | navy beans | lobster | cooked oatmeal |
| avocado | spinach | cream of rice | yogurt | eggs | creminis | hazelnuts | eggs | shrimp | beer |
| pumpkin seeds | collard greens | beef | milk | shiitakes | sweet potatoes | pecans |  | pork tenderloin | red wine |
| sesame seeds | turnip greens | ground beef | avocado |  | turnip greens | oats |  | beef | hard cider |
| almonds | broccoli | beef tenderloin | bananas |  | baked potato | lima beans |  | lamb | grits |
| pistachios | black-eyed peas | buffalo sirloin |  |  | spinach | chickpeas |  | chicken | black bean soup |
| pecans | navy beans | ground bison |  |  | sunflower seeds | navy beans |  | turkey | baked potato |
| sunflower seeds | salmon | porterhouse |  |  | pumpkin seeds | lentils |  | navy beans | carrots |
| acorn squash | acorn squash | beef stew meat |  |  | Brazil nuts | spinach |  | pinto beans | spinach |
| hubbard squash | lobster | pork tenderloin |  |  | walnuts | pineapple |  | lima beans | cantaloupe |

---

• Using `GROUPBY()` function applicable to `MS365` --> `Office Insiders` only.

```
=LET(
     _Data, A3:J16,
     _SingleCol, TOCOL(_Data,1),
     GROUPBY(_SingleCol,_SingleCol,ROWS,,0,-2))
```

---

Or, Using `BYROW()` or `MMULT()`

```
=LET(
     _Data, A3:J16,
     _SingleCol, TOCOL(_Data,1),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_SingleCol),
     _Counts, MMULT(N(_Uniq=TOROW(_SingleCol)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(_SingleCol))^0),
     HSTACK(_Uniq,_Counts))
```

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, A3:J16,
     _SingleCol, TOCOL(_Data,1),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_SingleCol),
     _Counts, BYROW(_Uniq,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(x=_SingleCol)))),
     HSTACK(_Uniq,_Counts))
```

---

- All the above formulas shown gives the number of counts for each unique records.
- Using `TOCOL()` function to convert the multiple ranges data into single column array excluding the duplicates.
- **Method 1** --> In the first method, used `GROUPBY()` function which is designed to `group`, `aggregate` and `sort` as per the fields we specify. However, the said function is in `Office-Insiders` hence until and unless you have enabled the option, this wont work and show as `#NAME!` error.
- **Method 2** --> Also starts with the `LET()` function, which makes easier to read and reduces the uses of redundant ranges/formulas.
- Like the first method, it first applies the `TOCOL()` function, then uses `UNIQUE()` function to return unique values, and lastly uses `MMULT()` function to return the counts which is the matrix product of the two given arrays.
- Finally, using `HSTACK()` to combine both the arrays returned using `UNIQUE()` and `MMULT()` function to return the desired output.
- **Method 3** --> Starts with the same steps as above except it uses `BYROW()` function to get the matching counts of each items.

---

However, if you find these methods as complicated then also you use the simplest one shown below as :

[image]

---

- Firstly, use `TOCOL()` & `UNIQUE()` function to return the multiple ranges into one array excluding the empties and duplicates. And place in a cell, lets say in `L2`

---

```
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(A3:J16,1))
```

---

- Finally, enter the following function to get the counts. Remember that i have taken the data range as `A3:A16` which you may need to change as per your suit. The following doesn't needs to be filled down, as it will spill. Where `L2` is the formula returned from above using `TOCOL()` and `UNIQUE()`

---

```
=COUNTIFS(A3:J16,L2#)
```

---

If you are still reluctant to follow the above, then you can use `POWER QUERY` which is available from `Excel 2010+` onwards for ,available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Value"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

<sup>Note: Formula cannot delete duplicates, instead it extract values when placed in a cell following specific conditions. Like I have shown above. You basically need `UNIQUE()` , `TOCOL()` & `COUNTIF()` or `COUNTIFS()` function to get the desired output</sup>

---

With your `Rough List` simply place this formula in any blank cell, where `List` is the name of the `Table`:

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(List),
     _Output, SORT(HSTACK(_Uniq, COUNTIF(List,_Uniq)),2,-1),
     VSTACK({"Nutrients","Counts"},_Output))
```

---

It is easier with `GROUPBY()` function if applicable:

```
=GROUPBY(List,List,ROWS,,0,-2)
```

---

Comment: Can't wait to experiment with your suggestions, but this will have to wait until tomorrow after a cup of coffee.  I must say, it is a rather impressive answer and I actually am a little intimidated to try it, but you've done all the hard work.  All I have to do is try to emulate it.  If both of these methods work — yours and the one from MGonet — I'll have to decide which of you should receive the green check mark.  It looks as if it might be a tough decision.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal regards only the first part (sorted list of products):
[image: Food]
You can place your list in an Excel Table, e.g. `Table1` and refer to this list as `Table1[List]`.
In columns `C` and `D` you get a list of unicates with their counts.
Formula in `C2` : `=UNIQUE(Table1[List])`
Formula in `D2` : `=COUNTIF(Table1[List],C2#)`
As a next step you can sort these two columns as shown in columns `F` and `G`.
Formula in `F2` : `=SORT(HSTACK(C2#,D2#),2,-1)`

Comment: Impressive answer and it looks to be a bit easier than the other provided, but I'm intrigued by both and look forward to trying them out tomorrow after a cup of coffee and a fresh mind.  And thank you for even using my very own list as an example.  Though I have since cleaned up the entries, I can see now that the one I initially provided included two different spellings of _Cantharellus cibarius_.  To be fair to myself, note that the Latin uses an "a" in the second syllable and not an "e" (the correct spelling).